# Type mismatch error in VBA when using mmult

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code this forumla in vba.

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(F124:F370-L124),G124:G370-L125)/246
```

The code in vba I written looks like this:

```
Sheets("1.A").Cells(124, 14) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("1.A").Range("F" & matchStartRow & ":F" & matchEndRow) - Cells(124, 12)), Worksheets("1.A").Range("G" & matchStartRow & ":G" & matchEndRow) - Cells(125, 12)) / (matchEndRow - matchStartRow)
```

But it is giving me a type mismatch error. Not sure where it is coming from

Comment: One issue you have is you are fully qualifing your ranges `Worksheets("1.A").Range("F" & matchStartRow & ":F" & matchEndRow)` but not the Cells, ie `Cells(124, 12)` rather than  `Sheets("1.A").Cells(124, 11)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is much easier to use `EVALUATE` either directly as

```
Sheets("1.A").Cells(124, 14) = Evaluate("=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(F124:F370-L124),G124:G370-L125)/246")
```

or with your variables

```
Dim strEval As String
matchStartRow = 124
matchEndRow = 370
strEval = "=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(F" & matchStartRow & ":F" & matchEndRow & "-L124),G" & matchStartRow & ":G" & matchEndRow & "-L125)/(" & matchEndRow & " - " & matchStartRow & ")"
Sheets("1.A").Cells(124, 14) = Evaluate(strEval)
```

Comment: + 1 Yeah. The third option would be to use the variables in `Sheets("1.A").Cells(124, 14).Formula` as well.

Comment: But didn't answer why there was a mismatch error.. although it worked, would like to know why there was a mismatch error.

Comment: Good to see you got it working. I did make one comment on your existing code - I will dig further if you want to get to the bottom of that issue.

Comment: yes. I tried that comment as well but it didn't work.. and most importantly, thanks a lot..